# Expected values with power functions

Tags: probability, expectation

$X_1,\dots,X_T$ are i.i.d. random variables.

What is the expected value of the following function:

$$ \left (\sum_{t=1}^T X_t^a\right)^{(1/a)} $$

as a function of $a$ and $T$?

a. What is the best way to calculate this value explicitly, when the distribution of the $X_t$'s is known? E.g. suppose each $X_t$ is a discrete variable which equals 3 with probability 0.5 and 7 with probability 0.5, how can I compute the expectation of the above expression as a function of $a$ and $T$?

b. What is a symbolic, approximate expression (e.g. in big-Oh notation) for the expectation, when $a$ is constant and $T\to \infty$?

EDIT (a hint from my advisor): By [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder's_inequality) for sequences, if the $X_t$ are non-negative and $a\geq 1$, then for every non-negative sequence $Y_t$:

$$ \left (\sum_{t=1}^T X_t^a\right)^{(1/a)} \cdot \left (\sum_{t=1}^T Y_t^q\right)^{(1/q)} \geq  \sum_{t=1}^T X_t Y_t$$

where $\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{a}=1$ (so $q=\frac{a}{a-1}$).

If we take the sequence $Y_t=1$ for all $t$, then this becomes:

$$ \left (\sum_{t=1}^T X_t^a\right)^{(1/a)} \geq \frac{\sum_{t=1}^T X_t}{T^{1/q}}$$

So a lower bound on the expected value, when the variables are i.i.d, is:

$$\frac{\sum_{t=1}^T E[X_t]}{T^{1/q}} = \frac{T E[X_1]}{T^{1/q}} = T^{1-1/q} E[X_1] = T^{1/a} E[X_1]$$

This is only a lower bound.

Comment: Assuming $E(X^a)$ exists, $\frac 1 T \sum_1^T X_i^a\to E(X^a)$ a.s.

Comment: $$E(S)=2^{-T}\sum_{k=0}^T{T\choose k}(3^ak+7^a(T-k))^{1/a}$$